# The ResourceBundle.class in rt.jar is said to miss

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, rt.jar

I have a recurrent problem with Eclipse: when I try to launch my plugin Eclipse application, it often opens a new tab to "attach a missing source" in jre7\lib\rt.jar. I must be a bug since it usually works and I have never modified that file.

There is a screen of the problem: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/436657Bug.png

The only way I found to fix it is to delete the ".metadata" of the project each time it does that... and to loose all my preferences, breakpoints and so.

Answer (score 0):

Keep rt.jar in your classpath. And clean the project.

Comment: I cleaned the project but it didn't solve the problem. What do you mean by "keep rt.jar in your classpath" ?